# Ruby DataMapper, how to do query comparing two columns

Tags: ruby, datamapper

Let's say I have two properties in the Table A:
property a, Integer
property b, Integer

I want to find all rows where a < b.

Is it possible to use DataMapper all method to do so?

I know how to query this in raw SQL of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A.all(:conditions => ["a < b"]) will do, but is there any better way?